# Listview theming issues

Tags: android, listview

This is probably a simple question, but I really have tried searching here and google with no joy.

I can make listview lists by following the many tutorials on the net. The problem is, they always seem to churn out lists that don't seem similar in appearance to the bulk of the lists I see in apps.
For example, I've attached a screenshot of a menu in the Chainfire3D app. It uses the 'standard' blue dividers, white titles and smaller blue 'description' text for the second line. This style of menu/list is used in many of the market apps I have. Feedly is another example.
Every time I create a listview I get either all white text (or text which is themed by whatever I have used in the layout). 
Are there 2 line menus, with white and blue text that are easy to create, because I'm having to specify the colours in XML etc if I want them to look this way. 
Also, to get two line listviews I have been using a custom adapter and 2 textviews on top of each other in a layout. I tried a 'simple_list_item_2' and that worked but again it didn't take this 'standard' theme. I'm sure I'm missing something.
Anyone know what?

Ideally, can someone share some code with me that will create a 2 item listviews, ideally (if poss) with a suitable adapter that will allow the running of different activities based on menu items presses. Here's hoping you can help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to customize your layout.

You can find good examples [here](http://www.hambonious.com/2010/06/customizing-android-listview-colors.html) or [here](http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2010/03/15/android-%E2%80%93-applying-alternate-row-color-in-listview-with-simpleadapter/).

Comment: Thank for the answer. The posts you link two are good, but they show me how to customise. What I want is NOT to customise. I want the stock listview style. Like in my default Android settings menus, like in the image I linked to or countless other apps. All the examples I try make non standard colour layouts, even if they don't specify colours in the layout. Also almost all in app examples I see use this stock type style. I can't believe they are all coding it colour for colour.